# How to show spinner while typing in input field

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to start spinner while typing. When I stop doing it, then it should match the username, if username exists, show tick icon otherwise show cross icon and also minimum letter should be 4 .

I tried it with using two icons, tick & cross. I kept the minimum letter condition as 4 and it worked fine, when I remove the characters those tick or cross should disappear, but it does not.

How to add spinner and also how to avoid this problem?

```js
console.log($("#id_username"));
$("#id_username").keyup(function() {


  $("#lola").show();
  if (this.value.length < 4) {
    return
  }
  var username = $(this).val();
  console.log(username);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/validate_username/',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'username': username,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.is_taken) {
        $("#lola").html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        $("#lola").css("background-color", "red");

      } else {
        $("#lola").html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">

  <input class="form-control" id="id_username" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" required />

  <div class="input-group-addon" id="lola" style="display:none">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you did `.show()`, where is `.hide()` ?

Comment: After hiding it how to add spinner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just returning from the function if the length is `<4`. You'll need to hide it and then return.

```
console.log($("#id_username"));
$("#id_username").keyup(function() {


  if (this.value.length < 4) {
    $("#lola").hide();
    return
  }
  $("#lola").show();
  var username = $(this).val();
  console.log(username);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/validate_username/',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'username': username,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.is_taken) {
        $("#lola").html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        $("#lola").css("background-color", "red");

      } else {
        $("#lola").html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
      }
    }
  });

});
```